# What is the unit of two point distance calculation in here map?

Tags: here-api

I am calculating distance between two point using heremap method as follows:

```
var pointStart = {
 lat: '40.822197', 
 lng: '-98.188853' 
}

var pointEnd = {
 lat: '43.083113', 
 lng: '-77.589063' 
}
var p1 = new H.geo.Point(pointStart.lat, pointStart.lng);
var p2 = new H.geo.Point(pointEnd.lat, pointEnd.lng);
var dist = p1.distance(p2);
```

What is the unit of distance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is meters. You can find it in documentation - https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-geo-point.html#h-geo-point__distance

distance (other) : {number}

Returns the distance between the point and the point supplied by the caller. The method uses the Haversine formula. The altitude is not considered.

Parameters:

other:
    {H.geo.IPoint}

```
An object representing the point to which to calculate the distance
```

Returns:

```
{number} 
A value indicating the distance between the given location and the location supplied by the caller in meters
```